# NEST Elastic search empty values in Documents result

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Elastic search noob question.

After reading some questions on SO I figured out to POST some data to my Index but I'm having some trouble getting back results.

I'm getting one document (as expected) but all properties are empty. The number of bytes 740 match the number of bytes received in Postman. I suspect the data isn't mapped right somehow..

Code:

```
var client = CreateCloudClient();
var indexName = "index-b";
var mustClauses = new List<QueryContainer>();

mustClauses.Add(new WildcardQuery
{
    Field = new Field("FirstName"),
    Value = "*ralf*"
});

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<ProfileEntity>(indexName)
{
    Query = new BoolQuery { Must = mustClauses }
};

var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync<ProfileEntity>(searchRequest);
if (searchResponse.Hits.Any())
{
    var person = searchResponse.Hits.First();
}
```

Debugger result
[image: [![result][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld5Wb.png]

When using Postman:

```
GET ../westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/index-b/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "FirstName": "*ralf*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "index-b",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "0ec623e7-3837-4e83-808d-fed01398d1ab",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "Id": 0,
                    "ProfileId": "0ec623e7-3837-4e83-808d-fed01398d1ab",
                    "FirstName": "Ralf",
                    "LastName": "de K",
                    "BirthDate": "1999-09-19T00:00:00Z",
                    "BirthPlace": "Zwolle",
                    "BirthPlaceLocation": {
                        "Longitude": 41.9074,
                        "Latitude": -78.7911
                    },
                    "City": "Zwolle",
                    "Email": "email@example.org",
                    "ObjectIdentifier": "0ec623e7-3837-4e83-808d-fed01398d1ab",
                    "MobileNumber": "06123123123",
                    "Height": 2,
                    "BodyBuild": 0,
                    "Ethnicity": 8,
                    "Education": 3,
                    "Gender": 2,
                    "Created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "Updated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my own mistake. I used `ElasticLowLevelClient` to add a new index and I (probably) should have used `ElasticClient` because the first adds the index with pascal casing and the latter camel casing. Could be a config/setting but usinf ElasticClient fixes my problem.

Comment: You can configure the POCO property -> JSON field casing conversion globally with `DefaultFieldNameInferrer(Func<string, string>)` on `ConnectionSettings`. For pascal case, `DefaultFieldNameInferrer(s => s)`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#camel-casing